# Freelance Insurance for C2C Arrangement

Tags: llc, insurance

I'm preparing to sign an agreement to work as a freelance contractor using a corp2corp arrangement with my LLC.  I know nothing is hard and fast until I get actual quotes.  Unfortunately, actual quote can take a week or more to get back.  Can anyone give me any insight from their experience on what annual expectations I can expect (e.g. $5k, $20k, etc.) to pay for insurance...

> **Commercial General Liability Insurance:**
>
> - Each Occurrence Limit: $1,000,000
> - General Aggregate Limit: $2,000,000
> - Products-Completed Operations Limit: $1,000,000
> - Personal and Advertising injury Limit $1,000,000.
>
> **Workers' Compensation Insurance:** as required by state.
>
> **Employers Liability Insurance:** $1,000,000 per occurrence.
>
> **Excess/Umbrella Liability Insurance:** $3,000,000 per occurrence.
>
> **Errors and Omissions Liability Insurance** and/or **Professional Liability Insurance:** $2,000,000 per occurrence.

Comment: I pay about $500/yr for general liability insurance for my new LLC (in NJ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my small business - doing software development - I forked out about $1000/yr for just general liability and professional liability.  Your mileage may vary.

The quote shouldn't take a week, though.  Something seems "off" to me.